# JML not null variants?

Tags: java, arrays, null, invariants, jml

i have a JML questions. what is the difference between

```
/*@ invariant array_ != null; */
```

and declaring it as

```
protected /*@ non_null */ Object[] array_;
```

regarding the elements of array_? What property holds for them in each case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> regarding the elements of array_? What property holds for them in each case?

Nothing is said about the elements. The only thing that is guaranteed is that the `array_` reference is not null.

Note the difference between

```
Object[] array = null;
```

and for instance

```
Object[] array_ = { null };
```

or

```
Object[] array_ = { };
```

The first line would violate the invariant, while the latter two would be allowed, as `array_` would point to an actual array (even though this array may only contain null elements or even no elements at all).

---

Another difference is that in the `invariant array_ != null;` approach, `array_ != null` must only hold before after each method, while if you use the `non_null` pragma `array_ != null` must hold at every control point throughout the program.

Comment: Hey aioobe, maybe you can also tell, why i get an ESC-warning here: //@ ensures \old(x_) != 0 ==> \result == array_[first_]; The Error is: Postcondition possibly not established (Post)

Comment: And whats the implementation?

Comment: tahnk you, fixed it in the meantime! :)